# Why aren't Xcode "landmarks" (// MARK:) working porperly on my systems?

Tags: macos, mac, xcode

If I type the following in Xcode in a source file

```
// MARK: Test1
// MARK: - Test 2
```

and then open the symbol overview menu (that lists all functions, classes, methods in a file), it should look like that

[image: That's the way it should look]

and apparently it also looks that way for other people. Yet on my computer it looks like that

[image: The way it actually does look]

What's going on here?

And when I type

```
// MARK: Test1
// MARK: -
// MARK: Test 2
```

It should also look like in the first image and it also does for other people but on my computer it looks like that

[image: Even worse]

How can this be? I'm having this issue since Xcode 5 and Mac OS 10.8 and I continue to have it with Xcode 6 and Mac OS 10.10. I even have it on two different completely unrelated Macs (with completely unrelated user accounts). I always thought that this is a general bug in Xcode, I even filed a bug report at Apple but today I found out on Stackoverflow that this actually seems to work fine for other users (they posted screenshots and none of them had such a strange issue). Of course that is not a programming question, that's why I took it here. What strange system setting could cause such a ridiculous bug?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is the original behaviour of `// MARK:`. Instead, you should try:

```
#pragma mark Test1
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Test2
```